# Error copying directory from a remote host to another remote host with 'scp'

Tags: ssh, scp

From my laptop, I'm trying to copy a directory of files from one Raspberry Pi (`pi@192.168.2.22`) to another (`pi@192.168.2.21`):

```
~/example$ scp -r pi@192.168.2.22:~/example/files_to_send pi@192.168.2.21:~/example
```

but I keep getting this error message after I enter the password for `pi@192.168.2.22` (the host from which the directory is to be copied):

```
pi@192.168.2.22's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

I've tried deleting the ECDSA fingerprints in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for each of the devices, and generating new ones by reconnecting each host together again with `ssh`. I have also ensured that the home directories (and all their contents) have the correct permissions, owner and group.

Also, if access the Raspberry Pi that I'm trying to copy from (`pi@192.168.2.22`) with `ssh`, and do the following:

```
~/example$ scp - r files_to_send pi@192.168.2.21:~/example
```

It works fine.

I'd like to know why using `scp` to copy from a remote host to another remote host isn't working.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I discovered the `-v` option for `scp` ; here its entry in the `scp` `man` page:

> Verbose mode.  Causes scp and ssh(1) to print debugging messages about their progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems.

So, I added this to the command, and this indicates that the authentication to `pi@192.168.2.22` is successful. However, when `pi@192.168.2.22` later attempts to authenticate to `pi@192.168.2.21`, the following messages are printed and the connection fails:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Comment: Can you actually `ssh` into the other machine? Also,  have you tried this syntax: `scp -r directorytosend pi@192.168.2.21:~/example/`

Comment: Yes, `ssh` works fine for all machines. The syntax you suggested works (from `pi@192.168.2.2`). Cheers

Comment: I'll post it as a answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'd still like to know why remote host to remote host isn't working...

Comment: Do you mean remote host to local host?

Comment: No. Apparently - according to this article https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ssh-and-scp-howto-tips-tricks/ - you can copy a file from one remote host to another by using the following syntax: `scp user@remote_host_source_IP:/path/to/directory/file user@remote_host_destination_IP:/path/to/directory_for_file`

Comment: It seems strange that this isn't working, when I can `ssh` between the two...

Comment: With the way your question is worded, it seems as though you are trying to copy from your local machine to a remote machine hence the confusion. Try this syntax: `ssh pi@192.168.2.22 scp -r ~/example/files_to_send pi@192.168.2.21:~/example`.

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that. Thanks for the input BTW!

Comment: You can also try using `strace` in front of the command to see where the system call is failing.

Comment: `scp -3 -r pi@192.168.2.22:~/folder_to_copy pi@192.168.2.21:~/target_to_be_copied_to`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, when I tried that, I got a weird double password prompt mashup: `pi@192.168.2.22's password: pi@192.168.2.21's password:`. It wouldn't let me authenticate...

Answer (score 0):

When you run an `scp` on a local client between two remote systems, like this:

```
scp remote1:file remote2:
```

You are authenticating to `remote1` from your local, as expected, but then it is `remote1` that authenticates to `remote2` directly. The file transfer is NOT sent via your local client as you might expect.

To tell `scp` on the client to authenticate to both remote hosts and to manage the file transfer itself you need an additional flag:

```
scp -3 remote1:file remote2:
```

In your situation I expect that the first Pi doesn't have a certificate-based login *that works without manual involvement* set up to the second, so the authentication fails. (Bear in mind your keys appear to require a passphrase to unlock, and that isn't available on the first Pi when it tries to communicate with the second.)

---

OK, so I can repeat your issue when I have no certificate based authentication set up. It seems that to transfer between two remote systems you *must* have certificate-based authentication (i.e. no password required).

Comment: Hi @roaima. Thanks for posting. I've tried using the `-3` option, but this presents me with a mashup of two password prompts side by side: `pi@192.168.2.21's password: pi@192.168.2.22's password:`. When I try entering a password, it responds with `Permission denied, please try again`, then presents me with another prompt: `pi@192.168.2.22's password`. But, after I enter it, I then get the message: `Connection closed by 192.168.2.22 port 22`. I'm stumped that this is also not working...

Comment: What, you get password prompts? Were you getting those on your initial `scp` attempts too?

Comment: Yeah, and with my initial attempts I got a prompt for the source host (`pi@192.168.2.22`), but it would crash before I saw the prompt for the destination host (pi@192.168.2.21).

Comment: @R.Neville answer updated. I'll see if I can find anything definitive on this for you.

Comment: Thank you @roaima! I setup an RSA key for `pi@192.168.2.22` (following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server), and it works fine now (`scp -r pi@192.168.2.22:~/example/files_to_send pi@192.168.2.21:~/example`)! I appreciate you putting in the time to discover this :)

Comment: I'll just add that this method won't work if you set a passphrase for the key. Without one, it works fine.